# datatables didnt working with symbols �

Tags: php, json, datatable

I'm using datatables and json. well it working if there's no this symbol � on my datatables. But when i have that this �  on my datatables is show warning

```
DataTables Warning : table id=tbl_prkp - Invalid json not responding blalalala..
```

When i'm searching on mysql database, i found on my table there's symbol like "²" or "~" or like antoher symbol like thats on my description. How do i replace thats symbol? Cause is make not showing on my DataTables. Sorry whit my english.,

Update :
Solve!! Thank's to Lea Tano!!!

Comment: You shouldn't have any ? symbols to replace in the first place. How do you generate these tables? It almost sounds like you're trying to open a database in a text-editor rather than the associated program. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: like i said i  dont know how to replace that (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uft8_encode` and `uft8_decode` This will convert your data  from the ISO-8859-1 encoding to UTF-8 and vice versa. Make sure to store your data correctly.

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Example: https://3v4l.org/KI9A3

Comment: Is work!!! I didnt know uft8_encode and uft8_decode for that!! Tq again!!!